# Missing dependencies in new Visual Studio 2019 projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Today I want to create a new project via Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise (V16.7.7). By default, the dependencies are missing:

[image]

I cannot start the Project via F5:

[image]

The Output Window shows 0 errors:

[image]

I can see the same behavior when I create a new Blazor-WA project.

I have re-installed the SDK (Microsoft .NET Core SDK v3.1.403) which not solves the problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: which .net core SDK have you installed? You need 3.1.403 for VS16.7

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes, I have installed the latest SDK 3.1.403

Comment: look in [build configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2019) if project is selected to be build